# How to remap an unknown key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a standard QWERTY keyboard not that really matters, just That I just a few extra keys I don't use. (Menu, Winleft, Winright)
I want to map them to the three extra keys on an OADG 109 only I don't know the "names" of the three keys (the one to the left of the space bar and the two on the right, before the  corresponding alt keys)

I know the command to remap is xmodmap -e "keysym Menu = [Name/Function of new mapping]"
is there a way for my to get this information or does someone know 
I tried looking online already

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/KB_Japanese.svg

Answer (score 0):

you could look in systemsettings -> keyboard -> shortcuts and resign using the GUI

Comment: If I cant enter the Key I want how am suppose to use the GUI to reassign it

Comment: **reassign to it